# Raspberry Pi camera coding questions

Tags: gpio, python, raspicam, picamera, gpiozero

I've been coding a little portable Pi camera using a Raspberry Pi Zero, the HQ camera module, and a WaveShare 1.44-inch screen. I've succeeded in programming a button to take a photo, and a button to shut things down. I've also succeeded in changing basic settings like the shutter speed and ISO within Python using `gpiozero`. Now, this doesn't sound very impressive, I know, but it's a win for me as I'm extremely new to the world of coding.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
from gpiozero import LED, Button
from subprocess import check_call
from signal import pause
import picamera
import time

bwhite=Button(21)
bblue=Button(16)
borng=Button(20)
bgrey=Button(4)

pc=picamera.PiCamera()
running = True
timestamp=datetime.now()
pc.resolution = (1920, 1080)
pc.sharpness= 50
pc.shutter_speed = 90
#pc.iso = 100
def picture():
    pc.capture('pic'+str(timestamp)+'.jpg')
def shutdown():
    check_call(['sudo', 'poweroff'])
filename = ('vid'+str(timestamp)+'.h264')

pc.start_preview()
bwhite.when_pressed=picture
bblue.when_held = shutdown

try:
    while running:
        print('Active')
        time.sleep(1)
            
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pc.stop_preview()
    running = False
    
pause()
```

Here are a few things I need help with:

- The WaveShare LCD hat has a 4-way D-pad with a center click. I want to be able to change the ISO in chunks (ie 100, 200, 400, 800, etc.) with the left and right direction and change the shutter speed in chunks with the up and down. The D-pad is essentially just using four buttons so I know how to signify those with `GPIO Zero`, it's just the changing values I'm not sure how to handle.
- I have no clue how to get video recording to function properly. I have a button that I want to use to both start and stop recording (click ones to begin and click again to end) but all of my attempts on that front have been folly.
- The last thing is I want to be able to use the HDMI port on the  Raspberry Pi and "overwrite" the LCD hat signal. Right now, nothing happens when something is plugged into the HDMI port.

Any help you could give a novice coder who's out of their depth would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is multiple questions. You should approach this problem like someone would eating an elephant ... one bite at a time. Instead of asking multiple questions, prioritize one and edit your question appropriately. Once that is working pick the next item off your list.

Comment: look at all the code that relates to a button press that results in a picture being taken ... do same for one of the joystick clicks ... when joystick click takes a picture, then modify code to change ISO instead